# Mover drawline izquierda a derecha y anchar linea

Tags: java

estoy intentando mover una draw line de izquierda a derecha, pero no logro mover la drawline completa esta solo se agranda. tambien no encuentro como poder engrosarla.

```
import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


    public class Grafico1 extends JFrame {

        private final JPanel contentPane;

        /**
         * Launch the application.
         */

        private int columna;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Grafico1 frame = new Grafico1();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Create the frame.
         */
        public Grafico1() {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(null);

            JButton bi = new JButton("Izquierda");
            bi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    columna=columna-20;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            bi.setBounds(105, 482, 89, 23);
            contentPane.add(bi);

            JButton bd = new JButton("Derecha");
            bd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    columna=columna+20;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            bd.setBounds(556, 482, 89, 23);
            contentPane.add(bd);
            setBounds(0,0,800,600);
            columna=300;
        }

        public void paint (Graphics g)
        {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor (Color.red);
            g.drawLine (columna, 200, 200, 200);
        }


    }
```

Comment: JFrame es un Component, ya intentaste usar paintComponent en vez de paint?

Comment: además deque con paint... creo que tenías que mandar llamar a repaint de manera manual al final de tu paint sobreescrito...

Answer (score 1):

Logre engrosar la linea con las siguientes linea de codigo:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
```

clase pública **BasicStroke** Define un conjunto básico de atributos de representación para las primitivas gráficas trazadas. Estos atributos describen la forma de un bolígrafo dibujado a lo largo de la trayectoria del camino y las decoraciones aplicadas donde se unen los segmentos del camino y donde comienzan y terminan. Estos atributos incluyen:

- anchura

El ancho de la pluma medido perpendicular a su trayectoria.

- tapas de los extremos

La decoración del camino donde comienzan y terminan los segmentos de línea.
la línea se une
La decoración de la ruta entre segmentos de línea conectados.

- atributos de guión

La definición de cómo hacer un patrón de guiones a lo largo de la trayectoria de la ruta creando nuevos segmentos que alternan entre secciones opacas y transparentes.

Comment: Sería útil para otros con el mismo problema, que des una explicación de por qué ese código lo resuelve